# can someone help me with a MATLAB function that changes the color space from RBG to ych1tch2?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to write a MATLAB function that coverts from RBG to ych1ych2.

```
Y = 0.299\*R + 0.587\*G +0.114\*B  
Ch1 = R - (G+B)/2  
Ch2 = (√(3)/2) \* (B-G)
```

[image: screen capture of conversion in matrix form]

Comment: what is ych1ych2 ?!

Comment: you have the formula, so just.... apply the formula ? But how matlab should interpret a negative pixel value ?

Comment: This site is to ask questions about programming. “Can someone help me?” is not a question about programming. There are other places intended to find people to work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert RGB to the luma, chroma cyan-red, chroma green-blue system of Carron (YCh1Ch2), the conversion matrix you need is

```matlab
rgb2ych1ch2 = [ 0.299 0.587 0.114 ; 1 -0.5 -0.5 ; 0 -sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2 ];
```

(This is just the three equations you present converted directly to matrix form.)

You can then convert by multiplying this matrix with your rgb values:

```matlab
ych1ch2 = rgb2ych1ch2 * rgb;
```